# Parse through JSON in Parse.com Cloud Code and Stripe

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, html-parsing, stripe-payments

I'm trying to parse through the DOM object you can find via this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#customers), which shows the JSON response when accessing the Stripe API. I'm doing this with the Parse.com Cloud Code SDK which prevents the use of jQuery. Does anyone know how to do this? Specifically I'm trying to access the subscription object of the customer to see if a subscription is 'active'. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get your response through Parse.Cloud.httpRequest

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
{
    url: 'yourUrlRequest.com'
    success: function(httpResponse) 
    {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        var subsObject = jsonResponse.subscriptions;
        // access subsObject.object, subsObject.total_count, subsObject.has_more, subsObject.url etc.
        // ...
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) 
    {
        response('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status)
    }
});
```

If you are getting the API response some other way, just JSONify it ands then access the fields through dot notation (in the same way as above).

Comment: this is a decent answer but it doesnt fully answer the question. ill still give you an upvote for effort !

Comment: the url would have to look like this:   url = 'https://' + skey + ':@api.stripe.com/v1/customers/' + request.params.customerId + '/subscriptions/' + request.params.subscriptionId,

Comment: you would need a subscriptionId, which I dont know how to get

Comment: Oh I see, so your problem is more getting the result from the API, rather than parsing it and accessing the fields?

Comment: My problem is both to be honest.